# Using DataTable with child row with .net 5

Tags: datatables

I tied to create child row as instructed in  https://datatables.net/. But unfortunately it is not working for me, it is not showing the plus sign to expand my row to see the additional information.
This is my view, can anyone tell me what is my mistake?

```
<div class="container">


<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="tn-pagetitle">
        <h3 style="font-weight:bold;"> Instructor</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="indent4">
        <partial name="_messageContainer" />
    </div>
    <table id="StudentInfo" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
           width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               
                <th></th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>MI</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Student TWRAID </th>
                <th>Race </th>
                <th> </th>


            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
   
</div>
```

and the Ajax part is below that should take care of adding plus sign to the each row.

```
<script>
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Full name:</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.zipCode + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.has600Permit + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   var table = $("#StudentInfo").DataTable({
      
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("get_Student_Info", "Instructor")",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }],
        "columns": [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
          // { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
          
            { "data": "firstName", "name": "First Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "mi", "name": "MI", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "lastName", "name": "Last Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "sex", "name": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "twraid", "name": "Last Name", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "race", "name": "Race", "autoWidth": true },
     
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-md "  style="color:white"  href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Instructor")/' + full.id + '">Edit</a>' + " " +
                            '<a class="btn btn-info btn-md"  style="color:white"   href="@Url.Action("Details", "Instructor")/' + full.id + '"> Details </a>' + " " +
                            '<a class="btn btn-info btn-md"  style="color:white"  href="@Url.Action("TransfertToREAL", "Instructor")/' + full.id + '"> Transfer to REAL </a>' + " " +
                            '<a class="btn btn-info btn-md"  style="color:white"  href="@Url.Action("UpdateStudent600Flag", "Instructor")/' + full.id + '"> Update student has 600 permit flag </a>' + " " +
                             '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-md"  style="color:white"  href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Instructor")/' + full.id + '"> Delete </a>' 
                 }

                },
        ]
    });
    $('#StudentInfo tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
   
});
```

Comment: Did you include the `+` and `-` icons in your page? That is not shown in your question. See the "CSS" tab in the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Comment: You can also find the two PNG files [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/tree/master/examples/resources) if you need them, but can't extract them from the example page.

Comment: IT is also achievable with rowGroup.startRender and you are able to click the row to expand/collapse? Would that suffice for a workaround or do you need the +- signs?

Comment: I need something like in the example https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html. I dont know where to include the + - sign ?

Comment: this is my table    <table id="StudentInfo" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
               width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   
                    <th></th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>MI</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Student TWRAID </th>
                    <th>Race </th>
                    <th> </th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

Comment: Re-read my comments - do they make sense? ***Did you look at the "CSS" tab I mentioned?***  Everything you need is in the example (and the files are available as per my comments).

Comment: I added the css file to my view and it still not showing me the +,- sign <style>
    td.details-control {
        background: url('~/wwwroot/Images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    tr.shown td.details-control {
        background: url('~/wwwroot/Images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    }
</style> and the css fie <link href="~/css/jquery.dataTable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: OK - but did you add the files as well? Just adding the CSS styles is not sufficient. If you _did_ add the files, then you should be able to hit them directly from a URL. And if you cannot, then that suggests they are in the wrong location, or there is some related config issue. But this is just guesswork.

Comment: And, just to add, you don't actually need to see the files for the click events to work (to open and close the child rows). Are the click events working?

Comment: Yes the clicking event is working but the +, - sign is not showing

Comment: Understood, thank you. So I think that now becomes a very different question: _How do I serve, and refer to, static resources such as images in my web application?_ It's no longer a DataTables question, I think. I expect that question has many answers on SO already (assuming my guess is correct - it may not be). But I cannot imagine using `~` in a URL is going to be valid. It's a URL not a file path.

Comment: (Small suggestion for the future: it can be difficult to read code squashed into comments, so you can edit the question to show this new information.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.